# How to change audio levels of sound card with same control names

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian, alsa, pulseaudio

I'm trying to write a script that automatically changes the playback/capture audio levels based on the device that is connected.

I'm using a MAYA44 USB+ sound with 4 ch in/out.

Thanks to a similar question here: [Terminal command to set audio volume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97936/terminal-command-to-set-audio-volume), 
I learned to use the following command:

```
amixer -c 2 sset Line,1 50%
```

The problem I have is that it seems like the capture control shares the same name as a playback control: Line

[image]

Doing

```
amixer -c 2 sset Line 50%
```

changes the values of BOTH controls.

As mentioned above, I'm writing a script to do this automatically,
so I don't want to go into Alsamixer and do it manually.

Is there a way to rename the controls so that there isn't a naming clash? Otherwise, is there some sore of suffix or prefix I can add to the 'Line' value to specify that I want to affect the CAPTURE device? Would using pulse audio in some way be another option?

Basically, how I can change the capture control values without affecting the playback values?

Answer (score 4):

I asked this same question here:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50596/how-to-change-audio-levels-of-sound-card-with-same-control-names

and got the answer from CL.

> Use `amixer -c2 controls` to list all the low-level controls.
>
> Then you can use `amixer -c2 cset ..` to select specific controls by
>   their unique ID number.

Running the command on my device:

```
>amixer -c 2 controls
numid=7,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'
numid=8,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Switch'
numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Switch',index=1
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Volume'
numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Volume',index=1
numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='Line Capture Switch'
numid=10,iface=MIXER,name='Line Capture Volume'
numid=2,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map'
numid=1,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map'
```

I had initially tried this but I couldn't get it to work. Only once I tinkered with it a bit more did I realize that the ID was in fact **'numid=10'** and not simply the integer **10**.